# How does c++ represent negative value

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

As i know binary equivalent of signed int is     11111111111111111111111111111111
and based on this, I'm trying to make Maximum and Minimum int value for my program without using limits.h header file. After run my below code i get Minimum value as -2147483648 and Maximum value is 0.  Here below is my code:

```
int MaxInt(){
      int MAX = -1;
      MAX = 0 << ((sizeof(int)*8)-1);

     return MAX;
}


int MinInt(){
      int MIN = 0;
      MIN  = 1 << ((sizeof(int)*8)-1);

     return MIN;
}
```

Whats wrong with my implementation.

Comment: What's wrong with `limits`? Why du you re-implement it?

Comment: "binary equivalent of signed int is 11111111111111111111111111111111" - what do you mean by this? Did you want to say "signed it has 32 bits in it"?

Comment: yes, this is 32 bit signed int @anatolyg

Comment: NO, this:  11111111111111111111111111111111 is NOT a signed int untill you declare it is (it might be unsigned int as well!), and even then it is a signed int *representation* for a single, specific value — not *a signed int* in general.

Answer (score 2):

In the function

```
int MaxInt(){
      int MAX = -1;
      MAX = 0 << ((sizeof(int)*8)-1);

     return MAX;
}
```

you at first assigned -1 to MAX and then overwrote its value. So this assignment does not make sense.

Also if to shift left 0 then you will get again 0 independing on how long you will shift the 0.:)

The simplest way to get the maximum value of object of type int for the 2's complement internal representation is the following

```
int MaxInt()
{
    int MAX = -1u >> 1;
    return MAX;
}
```

Or you can write simply

```
int MaxInt()
{
    return -1u >> 1;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr int MaxInt()
{
    return -1u >> 1;
}

constexpr int MinInt()
{
    return ~( -1u >> 1 );
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << MaxInt() << std::endl;
    std::cout << MinInt() << std::endl;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
2147483647
-2147483648
```

Comment: How i will make 0 the MSB?

Comment: @Maruf I am sorry I have not understood the question. As for the function I showed in my post then when -1u is shifted right one position the sign bit is filled with zero.

Comment: For negative number the MSB bit determined weather a number is positive or negative, in binary representation  -1 is equivalent  to all bit are 1 include MSB, and i try to make MSB bit set to 0, so that the number will be positive

Comment: @Maruf  I showed you in my post how to do this. What is the problem?

Comment: I understand your implementation and  i just clarified my question.

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation has several mistakes:

First, your representation of -1 assumes that `int` has a twos-complement 32 bit representation. This is not guaranteed for `int`. (It is for `std::int32_t`.)

Second, you assume that `int` has `sizeof(int)*8` bits. This again is not guaranteed at all.

Under all these assumptions, you still have a mistake in your implementation:

```
0 << ((sizeof(int)*8)-1);
```

can be written (mathematically, not in c++) as:

```
0 * 2**((sizeof(int)*8)-1)
```

Now, as you know, multiplying something with `0` results in `0`.

Assuming that twos-complement is given, the following simple implementations should work:

```
MIN = -1 << ((sizeof(int)*8)-1);
MAX = ~MIN;
```

Comment: `MAX = ~MIN` is incorrect (almost correct); `1 << ((sizeof(int)*8)-1)` invokes undefined behavior (`int` overflow); will almost always work but not guaranteed - better use `-1` instead of `1`.

Comment: @anatolyg Please actually read the answer that details how very wrong the OPs assumptions are. [Given the assumptions of the OP, the program is correct.](https://ideone.com/hL0QNQ)

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong about the `MAX = ~MIN` part - it's absolutely OK. Still, one should not rely on a result of `int` overflow, especially if it's so easy to fix (also, can only remove a downvote if the answer is edited).

Answer (score 1):

> Whats wrong with my implementation

```
MAX = 0 << ((sizeof(int)*8)-1);
```

Shifting zero by any amount will always be zero.

Comment: You can also invoke UB by shifting by certain amounts.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't specific to C++, but rather about 2's complement form. In 2's complement, the most-significant bit doesn't merely indicate the sign (that the value is negative) but is rather that power of 2 (that is, for an 8-bit 2's complement number, the most significant bit would represent -2^7).

To make the most negative number, only the most significant bit should be set.

```
  // Disclaimer: this should work for *most* devices, but it
  // is device-specific in that I am assuming 2's complement
  // and I am also assuming that a char is 8-bits. In theory,
  // you might find a custom chip where this isn't true,
  // but any popular chip will probably have this behavior:

  int number_of_digits_in_int = sizeof(int) * 8;
  int most_significant_digit_index = number_of_digits_in_int - 1;
  int most_negative_int = 1 << most_significant_digit_index;
```

To make the largest positive number, all positive bits should be set:

```
  // The complement of 0 has all bits set. This value, by the way
  // is the same as "-1" in 2s complement form, but writing it
  // this way for clarity as to its meaning.
  int all_bits_set = ~(static_cast<int>(0));

  // Using an XOR with the most negative integer clears the
  // most-signficant sign bit, leaving only positive bits.
  int largest_positive_int = all_bits_set ^ most_negative_int;
```

Or, more simply:

```
  // Since the most negative integer has only the negative bit set,
  // its complement has only the positive bits set.
  int largest_positive_int = ~most_negative_int;
```

As others have stated, though, you should just use `std::numeric_limits`. This will also make your code portable and work even on very bizaare devices that don't use 2s complement, for example, not to mention that the less code you write yourself, the fewer mistakes that you'll make.

Comment: Instead of `all_bits_set ^ whatever`, use `~whatever` - much clearer that way. Also, `(int)0` is kinda awkward (the casting is useless).